# What is included in an App Script runtime?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, quota

I have an app script that applies an array formula to one column, then copy-pastes these as values, thereby removing the formulas while retaining the values. This is done 30 times for 30 columns and returns ~8000 rows of data upon completion. In [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), it says that a script runtime has max 6 minutes per execution. However, running my script in the script editor goes beyond that based on the execution log.

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. Does the script runtime include the lagging part when the formulas
   are loading? I believe these are what contribute to the long
   execution time.
2. If I run the script via a time-based trigger or a
   button/image, will it still be able to run everything, just as it
   did when running the script from the editor?

Hoping for your insights on this. Thanks!

Comment: Ask only 1 question per post. Kindly remove your second question.

Comment: Are you using a Google Workspace account? I believe the link you referenced may be incorrect in that column.  In the past the runtime was listed as 30 minutes and in my experience that hasn't changed.